# voting master graduated

Tags: prepositions

Ground or infinitive in present perfect continuous tense
I have been starting saving nature . I have been starting to save nature. I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: I have been starting to save nature, or, better, I am starting to save nature.

Comment: What does saving nature have to do with graduation?

Comment: What does the title mean? Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: *I have started to save nature.*

Answer (score -1):

Only '***to start to*** ...'

According to Cambridge Dictionary some verbs (including ***start***) are followed by the Infinitive.

Some examples:

It began to rain.

She hopes to go to university next year.

My mother never learnt to swim.

Did  you remember to ring Nigel?